# Sec Ownership Filings (3,4,5) how are dead Insiders reported?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, sec

I recently looked into 3,4 and 5 filings on the sec, they are basically required when insiders (CEO’s, Officers, 10% owners, …) purchase stocks or derivates of their company.

These documents are highly structured so one can basically extract the exact amount of shares an insider owns at any point in time, in an automated matter. I tried it and it works great but there is one problem I could identify:

I tried it with Apple and got results like Tim Cook, Craig Federighi but also Steve Jobs. Obviously Steve Jobs doesn’t own any shares any more since he passed away yet these filings contain no indication of this event, setting the shares to 0 or anything else, obviously the shares did not go away, somebody inherited them but Steve Jobs is no longer in possession of them.

How is this reported? This surely requires some kind of reporting? The problem is that if I extract ownership data a computer can’t know about these events and insider filings would render wrong information.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: His estate may well own plenty of shares.